# Magento2 cannot override class Magento\GroupedProduct\Model\Product\Type\Grouped?

Tags: model, magento2, overriding

I was trying to override the above class `(Magento\GroupedProduct\Model\Product\Type\Grouped)`

Below is my `app/code/Test/CustomGrouped/etc/adminhtml/di.xml`

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\GroupedProduct\Model\Product\Type\Grouped" type="Test\CustomGrouped\Model\Product\Type\Grouped"/>
</config>
```

And below is the model class `app/code/Test/CustomGrouped/Model/Product/Type/Grouped.php`

```
<?php
namespace Test\CustomGrouped\Model\Product\Type;

class Grouped extends \Magento\GroupedProduct\Model\Product\Type\Grouped
{
    public function getAssociatedProducts($product)
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

I debug through the code, but it still goes to the core class rather using my overridden one. I do not want to use a plugin. I just want to know what am I missing here when overriding the class `Magento\GroupedProduct\Model\Product\Type\Grouped`

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

P.S. : I already checked with clearing the cache, generation etc. in var folder. But it didn't worked. I'm using Magneto EE 2.1

Answer (score 1):

Modifying the file `app/code/Best/CustomGrouped/etc/module.xml` to load my custom module after the core module worked for me.

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Best_customGrouped" setup_version="0.0.1" active="true">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_GroupedProduct"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

The issue was sine the namespace of My custom module started with letter 'B' it was listed before the Magento's GroupedProduct module in `app/etc/config.xml`. So I force my module to load after the Magento's one by using above code.